# Google-spreadsheet formula to get number ranks in column

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I'm looking for formula/function for google-spreadsheet. Sorry for the title, but let me explain. I have a column with 5 rows of numbers:

```
2
5
9
7
4
```

I want to loop through rows and create another column which will tell me rank of each cell. So, for example "2" is the lowest so it gets **1**. "9" is the highest to it gets **5** (highest rank, because there are 5 rows), "7" is second highest, so it gets **4**, etc. So, I want to achieve this:

```
1
3
5
4
2
```

So, in other words. For every cell in new column, I need to put value how high relevant number in other column is.
Can anyone help me with this? I'm using Google spreadsheet.

Comment: @pnuts Because often (if not almost always) excel solution works with google sheets. Like Bobby Orndorff said, RANK function works in Excel and in Google Sheets.

Comment: @pnuts downvote because of excel tag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google Sheets and Microsoft Excel have a RANK function that has the syntax...

```
RANK(value, data, [is_ascending])
```

Suppose your data is in cell range A1:A5 and you want the results in cell range B1:B5. Then you could place the formula...

```
=RANK($A1,$A$1:$A$5,1)
```

in cell B1 and fill down to cell B5.

Answer (score 1):

having the numbers in `A1` to `A5` put in `B1`:

```
=ArrayFormula(MATCH(A1,SMALL(A$1:A$5,(ROW($1:$5))),0))
```

and auto-fill it down

Comment: Why not just use `RANK` ?